# Which directory should custom git bash scripts be saved to in windows so that they can be called from anywhere?

Tags: windows-7, bash, bash-scripting, git-bash

I am learning how to use git bash for Windows and I want to start writing scripts to automate some of the git tasks I do. But where should I store the .sh files so that I can call them from any directory in git bash? Is there a standard directory they should be saved in?

At the minute I have to include a path to where the .sh file is. What I want is that when I am in git bash I can call the script just like I would any git command i.e. without a path.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit your `Path` environment variable to include the folder to your scripts.  Start --> Right click Computer --> Properties --> Advanced System Settings --> Environment Variables.

It is a System variable on Windows 7; separate each path with a semicolon.

After that, reload the command prompt and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can run them from anywhere that the script has permissions to.  I typically put my scripts in 'c:\scripts'.

Answer (score 0):

Save it into the folder `$HOME/bin`.

If the script uses the extension `.sh` and you want to avoid typing the `.sh` everytime; you have a few options:

1. Easy option is to add an alias in your `$HOME/.bashrc` like below

   ```
   alias mycmd='$HOME/mycmd.sh'
   ```
2. Another option is to rename the file and just remove the `.sh` extension (not recommended) this could break some scripts depending on that command.
3. Another option is to add a symbolic link.

   NOTE: You have to enable symbolic links during the installation.

   [image]

That's all.